# Ant task imported from build.xml in Gradle script is running automatically

Tags: ant, import, gradle, task

I have this Java project there I import an Ant build.xml file with some tasks, like this:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

task myTaskA(dependsOn: ':Modules:MyModule:assemble') << {
    // do stuff here...
}

compileJava.dependsOn(myTaskA)

configure(jar) {
    include 'classes.dex'
}

jar.dependsOn(antCompile)
```

The task `antCompile` comes from the Ant build.xml script. However, for some reason, this task is being called at start up when invoke `gradlew assemble`, **it doesn't even wait for the `jar`** task to start.

Also, the `antCompile` task is defined as the following target in build.xml:

```
<target name="antCompile" depends="-setup">

</target>
```

That Ant target, `-compile` is **always** the first task to be executed when I invoke `gradlew assemble`. This doesn't make any sense. That task is never invoked anywhere, it's only a dependency of `antCompile`. Why is it being executed?

This is, obviously, not what I want... How can I prevent such behaviors?

Comment: `antCompile` will run before `jar` because the build script says so (`jar.dependsOn(antCompile)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work as expected. The build script makes `jar` depend on `antCompile`, which according to your words depends on `-compile`. `assemble` depends on `jar`, so executing `gradle assembmle` should run `-compile` first.

In any case, it should be said that `ant.importBuild` has known limitations, and can result in differences in behavior compared to running the Ant build directly. Also you'll lose many of Gradle's advantages when not describing the build in terms of Gradle's own abstractions. Therefore I recommend to port the build to Gradle, rather than using `ant.importBuild` (which isn't used that often in the real world). Note that it's perfectly fine to reuse Ant *tasks* in cases where Gradle doesn't provide any equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, I was importing an Ant build because I was having difficulty to mimic the same behavior using Gradle only. There was a question for it already here on SO, but nobody answered it and I needed this ASAP. But after finishing my Gradle + Ant build, I've realized I now might be able to completely use Gradle for what I need as I understand exactly how to achieve the same result as with Ant (I didn't before).

Comment: Also, it still doesn't make much sense to me the task building order. I don't think it should work like that. I'm not sure what `-compile` is, did you mean `-setup`?

Comment: You mention `-compile` in your question.